# Looking for examples of decision tree workflow

Tags: wizard, workflow

We are going to be allowing our customers to request building permits online. I am thinking of of flowing the customer through a series of questions to make sure they know what information we need and so they get us the right information to process their permit.

I can't think of any sites right now that elegantly takes a person through a set of steps that then routes them to the right information. What I am think of is something like:

```
I want to .... a. build a fence
               b. reroof my house
               c. replace my siding
               d. replace a door
               ...
```

Then if they choose replace a door, then asks

```
I am replacing with a.... a. same size door
                          b. different size door (has more requirements)
```

The flow then eventually will arrive at filling out the form for the permit and sends to our staff for approval and so on.

I could easily use drop down lists and flow a user through the questions, but I am sure there could be a more elegant why to ask these questions of the users.

Can you point me to a couple articles or websites that have a good flow for this style of questioning?

Comment: Google search does this with predictive suggestions. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Go to [Hunch.com](http://hunch.com/browse/) and select **Feed**

Here there are 10 questions that needs to be answered which seamlessly come upon on completion of previous question. This closely relates to what you are looking as a pattern, but the site is precisely for a different context. The best part of the site is that it tries to understand personal interest and shows up information lately on our likings, similar to Pandora largely.

Will post, if I find some other similar sites.

Comment: Not sure I found what you were referring to, but I started to do their questionnaire. That is a user friendly way to ask these questions.

Comment: Hunch.com doesn't exist anymore; it was purchased by eBay and as of March 2014, redirects to the eBay site.